# Adding non class functions to generic TArray class

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, generic-collections

In `System.Generics.Collections`, the `TArray` type has class functions only.

For example:

```
class procedure Sort<T>(var Values: array of T); overload; static;
```

This implies the only accepted syntax is the following:

```
var
  Arr : TArray<integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 2);
  Arr[0] := 5;
  Arr[1] := 3;

  TArray.Sort<integer>(Arr);
end;
```

I would like to define an object's function in order to sort the values of the generic array using the following syntax:

```
var
  Arr : TArray<integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 2);
  Arr[0] := 5;
  Arr[1] := 3;

  Arr.Sort();
end;
```

Comment: The type ``TArray<T>`` in Unit ``System`` is not the same as the ``TArray`` class in ``System.Generics.Collections``. What about using a record helper? See your own [Q and the accepted A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42767205/11329562) for more details

Comment: @DelphiCoder: This is a different question, I want to use generic arrays

Comment: @Fabrizio That's not at all clear in the question though is it? `TArray.Sort<T>()` makes no requirement that you pass a generic array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Agree, it could have been easily misunderstood...
I've updated the question

Comment: That's an open request for quite some time: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-10336

Answer (score 1):

You can define helpers for non-generic dynamic arrays, or for fully specialized generic dynamic arrays. For instance, you can write:

```
type
  TMyArray1 = array of Integer;
  TMyArray2 = TArray<Integer>;

  TMyArrayHelper1 = record helper for TMyArray1
  end;
  TMyArrayHelper2 = record helper for TMyArray2
  end;
  TMyArrayHelper3 = record helper for TArray<Integer>
  end;
```

This allows you to add methods to the scope of such arrays.

So you can write

```
type
  TIntegerArrayHelper = record helper for TArray<Integer>
    procedure Sort;
  end;

procedure TIntegerArrayHelper.Sort;
begin
  TArray.Sort<Integer>(Self);
end;
```

However, what you cannot do is write:

```
  TMyArrayHelper<T> = record helper for TArray<T>
  end;
```

The compiler simply does not support generic helpers.

None of this is worthwhile in my view, just call:

```
TArray.Sort<T>()
```

directly. Adding a record helper, and having to make one for each element type that you wish to support, seems to me like a cost that does not justify the return.